# Put javax.jms.TextMessage using com.ibm.mq.MQQueue?

Tags: text, jms, ibm-mq, mq

We have existing application which uses com.ibm.mq.MQQueue.put(MQMessage) to send messages to Websphere queue.

We do not wish to change this message sender code.

On remote end we have queue listener which expects messages only of type TextMessage. So I was looking for option to TextMessage on remote queue. From IBM [MQQueue documentation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.javadoc.doc/WMQJavaClasses/com/ibm/mq/MQDestination.html#put_com.ibm.mq.MQMessage_%20MQDestination) I found that MQQueue.put() accepts arguments only of type MQMessage.

Please let me know, if it is possible any way. Also let me know if we have any alternative option.

Thanks,

Comment: Does the receiving application require JmsTextMessage or MQMessage of MQFMT_STRING format?

Comment: Receiving application requires message only in format JmsTextMessage.

Answer (score 0):

You set it in your MQ JNDI.  Go look up TARGCLIENT and TARGCLIENTMATCHING in the MQ InfoCenter at https://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.mq.csqzaw.doc/jm10910_.htm

Comment: As mentioned in documentation, these properties are used to put JMS or MQRFH2 header in message. I did not get how can I use it to put TextMessage on MQQueue? Did I miss anything?